# Sheets AppsScript to Generate Randomized a List of Numbers from 0 to 9 Without Duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title states, I am writing a script that will generate an array of randomized numbers from 0 to 9.

Here is the script I am working on currently. This successfully generates a list of numbers 0 through 9 in the range B15:B24, however there are duplicate values. How can I tweak this to post a unique/filtered list of numbers from 0 to 9?

```
function getRandomValues() {
  var values = []
  for (var i = 0; i <= 9; ++i) {
    values.push([Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1)]);
  }
  return values;
}

function RandomListGen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Squares");
  var range = sheet.getRange('B15:B24');
  var values = getRandomValues();
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getRandomValues() {
  let values = []
  for (var i = 0; values.length <= 9; i++) {
    var val = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
    if (values.indexOf(val) === -1) {
      values.push(val);
    }
  }
  return values.map((e) => [e]);
}
```

Basically you want to keep track of the list of random values, so you can tell if the new random value has already been used or not. If it is new, then add it to the array, otherwise keep going. In this case the for loop will keep going until the length of the final array is 9 (meaning the loop will likely run more than 9 times). Finally we re-map the values at the end so we end up with an array of arrays.